# Android SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST isn't fast enough

Tags: android, sensors, sampling

I'm using the sensors to balance a robot, but `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` only provides a 10Hz sampling rate, which is simply not fast enough. Is there a way of sampling even faster?

Is there a way of polling the sensors rather than waiting for a `SensorEvent` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way of sampling even faster?

`SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST` is a 0ms delay. You cannot have negative time, at least as far as physicists have determined. Hence, there is no "faster" delay than `SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST`.

Use [Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/traceview.html) to determine where your time is being taken up. It is possible that it is your code that is slowing down your processing.

> a way of polling the sensors rather than waiting for a SensorEvent ?

No, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I would check to optimize code as well, but why do you need faster than 10Hz? In my opinion you could just write a better 'balance' algorithm to reduce the need for a faster sample.

For instance when your robot is say 5 degrees to the right you'll try to correct for 4 degrees instead and reduce the need for a re-correction. Maybe I'm mistaken, but I'm open to suggestions too!

Comment: 10Hz is ok, but the sensors are too noisy and really need filtering and delay of even just 3 samples is too much    .. . .

Answer (score 0):

Since Android version 2.3, the sensors can be queried through the NDK, which will allow much faster polling.

Comment: What does much faster mean??? Can you give me a maximum samplerate??? I would need a 100Hz ... is this value reachable with NDK or SDK???

Comment: No, I haven't tried it myself. An year back I was hoping to try it sometime, but that plan hasn't materialised yet.