# How to get sensor data from the Light Sensor immediately upon change in android?

Tags: android, sensors, light

Well i have successfully obtained the light value, however, it is EXTREMELY delayed. Approx 3~5 seconds even when using .SENSOR_DELAYED_FASTEST also even when entering 0 as the rate. Its so slow. I have the program check light sensor values upon screen on then change brightness accordingly HOPING it would solve the horrible automatic brightness delay. but after messing around with it, it seems to me that this is simply a flaw in android. It simply cannot update fast enough. I have used getDefaultSensor() but according to android documention this value can be delayed/filtered, but upon reading another post on stackoverflow the getSensorList() and getDefaultSensor() return the same values and that getSensorList() is no different than getDefaultSensor()

The reason for my question is: Is this correct? Is android simply a fail at updating immediatly? its funny cause my Windows MOBILE(not phone) can update immediatly and i loved it. but with all android devices ive seen its the same thing. so is this just a flaw in androids programming? Is there a way for me as an app dev to fix this? or do we have to live with it?

Answer (score 0):

As I know you cannot get it faster. Please take a look on this question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5060690/1381641

Comment: thanks already saw that. but that didnt really clarify anything, my question is a bit different, im asking is it android's faulty NDK that is making it take forever? i remember reading that some have translated android to C# (makes me happY) im guessing this is a situation where they were trying to prove android is just too slow. (Cause it is)

Comment: Sensors polling frenquencies do not only depend on the Android API, but also on the sensor itself (for example, an accelerometer from a given provider can poll values every 6 ms when some others can't do it faster than each 15 ms). Make also sure (I reckon you already did though !) that it's the only sensor registered, as if you registered several the polling delay could be the one of the slowest.

Comment: Ah yes this is the response i was lookin for thanks greg. :) But the reason i hold android's api at fault is because my HTC HD2 is originally a Windows Mobile phone, so the hardware is staying the same but the OS is changing. And when in Windows Mobile 6.5.x the polling is changeable via a registry entry. And the smallest value i could change it to was 1ms and it polled at 1ms whilst killing the battery xD so i know the sensor can easily poll that fast. And yeah i only registered it once. Thanks for the info :)

Comment: So even registering the light sensor RIGHT before i need to get the values doesnt even help either :/ it still takes it ~3 seconds to refresh the values then return the results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the solution for your problem, but I do have an explanation for it. The Ambient light sensor has a delay because of the integration time downloads Sensor Box for android from the Playstore.

You will get the hardware ID of your ambient light sensor, then google search it, and you will get a PDF with technical details about that specific model number. Every Android or IOS phone does NOT use the same hardware.

In that PDF, you will get an integration time. It exists to keep the brightness control stable and delayed as well as sensible. If it is low, and you are in a disco your brightness level will keep on flickering. The same for outside, sometimes some shadows make it go up and down if the integration time is low. It will flicker more and will not be stable.

This will also cause harm to the backlight, so instead of taking single values they compile down the values of a big time interval. My integration time was 400ms. This value is sent to the processor, and then the decision is taken.

You could change this value. It is easy, AMD hard boh depends on your expertise like to update this you have to program the ALS unit by opening the phone, connecting a programmer to it, and connecting the pins in the right way. Then sending an 8 bit signal as mentioned in the PDF (if model is programmable).